# Mockito NullPointerException Inner Method code

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I am new to Mockito junit testing and am facing an issue. I would really appreciate if you guys can assist me with this.

```
class Activity{
   Connection conn;
   public SomeObject firstMethod() {
          /* *some code*  */
          SomeObject obj = secondMethod();
          return obj;
   }

   public SomeObject secondMethod(){
         /* *some code* */
         PreparedStatement ps = null;

         try{
             ps = conn.createStatement();
             ps.setBytes(1, *someString*);
         }catch(Exception e) { ... }

         /* *some code* */
         return someObject;
   }
}
```

Below is the test Class I have written. The unit test for secondMethod() works perfectly.

```
class ActivityTest{

  Activity activity;
  @Before
  public void setUp(){
     activity = new Activity();
     Connection conn = mock(Connection.class);
     activity.setConnection(conn);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSecondMethod(){
        /*  *works perfectly* */ 
  }

 @Test
 public void testFirstMethod(){

     SomeObject someObj = new SomeObject();

     // *I get error on below line*
     when(activity.secondMethod()).thenReturn(someObj);

     SomeObject result = activity.firstMethod();
     assertEquals(someObj, result);
 }
}
```

I get a NullPOinterException on     *when(activity.secondMethod()).thenReturn(someObj)*. When I traced the error stack the null value was the preparedStatement object ps. It occured on *ps.setBytes()* in secondMethod().

I do not understand this part. Why should I be getting an exception because of ps being null. I have written a rule for the secondMethod() which contains that code. 
Do I need to mock even PreparedStatement obj. It doesnt make sense to mock all internal objects as well since I have already defined rule for the method in which they are.

Can you guys please help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, that because you're calling the actual implementation of the `secondMethod()` function. sure you could avoid that by trying to mock all internal objects.

but, in this case. I think you could also try to use `doReturn/when` function rather than `when/thenReturn` function.

sample is like this.

```
doReturn(someObj).when(activity).secondMethod();
```

hope it helps ;)